# How to abort processing CMakeLists for current directory

Tags: cmake

I have a project structure like:

```
src/CMakeLists.txt
src/test/component1/CMakeLists.txt
src/test/component2/CMakeLists.txt
```

For the testing, I'm using Qt - however, I want to make sure that if Qt (or some other test-specific package is not found) I simply skip the package.

I tried

```
find_package(Qt4 QUIET COMPONENTS QtCore QtTestLib)
if (NOT QT4_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Qt4 not found - skipping building tests")
endif (NOT QT4_FOUND)
```

but that doesn't work like I want to since that still prevents the generation of the Makefiles.  The only way I can think is to put the entire body of the CMakeLists file into the body of the conditional.

Is there a way to say "skip processing the remainder of this CMakeLists"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the CMake [documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:return)

> - return: Return from a directory or function.
>
>   `return()`
>
> Returns from a directory or function.
>   When this command is encountered, it
>   caused process of the current function
>   or directory to stop and control is
>   return to the caller of the function,
>   or the parent directory if any. Note
>   that a macro is not a function and
>   does not handle return like a function
>   does.